# vsnprintf crash program in case %s is set with an integer

Tags: c++, printf

I'm writing a logger in C++ and to simplify entering lines I use vsnprintf function to build log line

```
void CLogger::RegManLog(const LogLevel & logLevelMask, char * Format, ...)
...
...
va_start(marker_, Format);
vsnprintf(buffer_ ,MaxLogBuffSize , Format, marker_)
va_end(marker_);
printer_ += buffer_;
...
...
```

every thing works great up until I accidently enter a number into a string

integer test = 10;
eg.: "now I'll show a string %s" , test

tried to add "try and catch", but I think vsnprintf does have throw, so it crashes any way.
tried to get return value from vsnprintf, it return value, while string are fine, when reaching the same issue, it crashes

any thoughts of I can i solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If gcc, you can tell it that your vararg is a printf like string, and will do additional format checking and give you a warning.  Check the 'format' function attribute at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: @user1693857 I bet you are using it without any warnings enabled...

Comment: (And now someone's upvoting... Mind blown, honestly...)

Comment: H2CO3 - mistake do happen, and when they do, you want to handle them, not letting the application crush.

Comment: @user1693857 "Crush" is when you love someone. The word you're looking for is "crash". Apart from that, this is why you compile your code using `-Wall` at least. Better, `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`.

Comment: H2CO3, but in my example there is no problem in compilation, only when malformed string is used. and some time people just enter the wrong string (shit happens)

and ye its crash and not crush... I think you got that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. %s expects to get a char*. When you pass in 10, it treats it like an address, goes there and kills your program.
2. If you wish to print integers, use %d. For more information look at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html
3. In C++ it is best to use other methods to accomplish what you need, like std::stringstream

Comment: I know that %s expects a char *, but sometimes, string is malformed and in this case I want to print the malformed string and not crush

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid printf and friends and instead use `std::stringstream` or `boost::format`

Comment: I believe boost::format ignores the format character and uses the type of the argument.

Comment: I'm using couple of modules in boost, but I'm trying to avoid using it as much as possible, from complex reasons.

stringstream, maybe I'll just use this.

but is there a way to catch before crush?

Comment: Nobody ever seems to explain *why* they can't use boost.  format is header only I believe so if you are already using another boost library, format won't add any build complications.  The correct term for a program exiting unexpectedly is "crash", not "crush".

Comment: No, there is no (easy) way to determine that the argument is the wrong type (or for that matter, the correct type, but pointing at garbage that causes a crash)

Comment: well if there is no solution for using vsnprintf, I'm guessing that boost or stringstream will have to do

Answer (score 1):

Well, when passed to `printf()` and family, the `%s` formatter is here as a placeholder for a -eventually const- `char *` pointer.

What is happening, is that your integer is read as a pointer, and it's likely that the memory address (`10` in your example) is invalid.

Comment: as I mentioned this is a malformed string, and this is why %s get an integer, the issue is that I want the system to print the bad string, and not crush